# webClient DownloadProgressChanged Event not working

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-7.3

I use this code to download a file from a link:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadURL), "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Documents\\AudioStreamerUpdate_" + rnd1.ToString() + ".zip");

//track the downloading progress                      
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label1updateinf.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
};
```

since the file is around 200 Mb, I want to track the progress of the download.

I have also tried this code:

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressUpdate);

private void webClient_DownloadProgressUpdate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

but it gives me this error:

> No overload for 'DownloadProgressCallback' matches delegate 'DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler'

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you attach the event handler *before* calling the download method:

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() =>InitializeComponent();
    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        SetWindowTheme(progressBar1.Handle, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        progressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;
        progressBar1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        var path =
            Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                Application.ProductName,
                "DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.12.2-win32.msi"
            );
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            // Attach event BEFORE downloading to receive progress
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                label1updateinf.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
            };
            try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://download.sqlitebrowser.org/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.12.2-win32.msi"), path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public extern static Int32 SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd,
                    String textSubAppName, String textSubIdList);

}
```

Comment: i moved it right after the declaration and it works ty